# Execute observable after another set of Observables have finished

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

So, I'm new to RxJS and was playing around with Angular 5, wondering how to accomplish the following:

Let's asume we have a form. When the page loads, we need 3 select to be populated with data from the server, so we have 3 Observables to accomplish this.

Now, we also have an observable for when the route params change (in that case, we have to get the requested record and populate the form):

```
// These 3 guys will get the required data for each select

this.countryService.getAll().subscribe(countries => {
  this.countries = countries;
});
this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe(categories => {
  this.categories = categories;
});
this.sectorService.getAll().subscribe(sectors => {
  this.sectors = sectors;
});


// And this is for the change in url

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  this.formDisabled = true;
  const id = params.get('id');

  // We get the resource based on the id param
  this.service.get(id).subscribe(contact => {
    this.contact = contact;

    this.form.reset(this.contact);

    this.formDisabled = false;
  }
});
```

Now, I need the callback of `this.service.get(id).subscribe()` to execute only after the 3 selects have been populated, i.e. when their respective callbacks have completed, otherwise we may end up trying to do things with the form when it's not completely built. I would like it to remain requesting the resource in parallel to the other 3 requests, but execute the callback (reset the form with it) only after the other 3 are completely done.

Answer (score 6):

It often helps if you try to layout the steps on **what** you want to achieve, instead of **how** you want to achieve. This trains you to think of in a more "reactive" manner.

1. Get the 3 dropdowns. This can be done in parallel

   - Assign the dropdown values
2. Retrieve the route params

   - Disable the form
3. Call service to retrieve by id which is from step 2
4. Do the rest:

   - Assign the values of contact.
   - Reset the form
   - Renable the form

Once you layout the steps, coding them as observables will be quite trivial:

```js
//Step 1: Call the dropdownsService in parallel
Observable.forkJoin([
    this.countryService.getAll(),
    this.categoryService.getAll(),
    this.sectorService.getAll()
])
    .switchMap(([countries, categories, sectors]) => {
        //Assign the dropdown values
        this.countries = countries;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.sectors = sectors;
        //Step 2: Retrieve the route params
        return this.route.paramMap;
    })
    .switchMap(({id}) => {
        //disable the form
        this.formDisabled = true;
        //step 3: Call the service to get contact info
        return this.service.get(id)
    })
    .subscribe(contact => {
        //Do the rest
        this.contact = contact;
        this.form.reset(this.contact);
        this.formDisabled = false;
    });
```

**PS**: I use object and array destructuring for more succinct and readable code.

### Edit:

If you want to call your `this.service.get` parallel to the `dropdown` service, put them in the same `Observable.forkJoin`:

```js
Observable.forkJoin([
    this.countryService.getAll(),
    this.categoryService.getAll(),
    this.sectorService.getAll(),
    this.route.paramMap.switchMap(({id}) => {
        this.formDisabled = true;
        return this.service.get(id);
    })
])
    .subscribe(([countries, categories, sectors, contact]) => {
        //Assign the dropdown values
        this.countries = countries;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.sectors = sectors;

        //Do the rest
        this.contact = contact;
        this.form.reset(this.contact);
        this.formDisabled = false;
    })
```

### Edit 2:

If you want to listen to the changes to any of the observable grouped together, regardless who emits first, use `combineLatest()`:

```js
Observable.combineLatest(
        Observable.forkJoin([
            this.countryService.getAll(),
            this.categoryService.getAll(),
            this.sectorService.getAll()
        ]),
        this.route.paramMap.switchMap(({id}) => {
            this.formDisabled = true;
            return this.service.get(id);
        })
    )
        .subscribe(([countries, categories, sectors, contact]) => {
            //Assign the dropdown values
            this.countries = countries;
            this.categories = categories;
            this.sectors = sectors;

            //Do the rest
            this.contact = contact;
            this.form.reset(this.contact);
            this.formDisabled = false;
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your tip on how to think the 'reactive way' is really helpful. This works just fine for ensuring the execution order of each Observable. Now, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to NOT wait for the step 1 to finish in order to start fetching the corresponding contact info (since this would add extra page load time for no reason). I would like to just get it from the service, but wait for Step 1 to finish in order to assign the retrieved contact.

Comment: @PabloMartínez Yes, definitely doable. Put your service to the forkjoin. See the edit.

Comment: That's really cool, it works beautifully for the first time. But I think that in future url changes, we are again executing the logic of the first 3 services. This is a trivial task, and probably Angular will reconstruct the 3 select again without us noticing it. But what if these were very complex and time-consuming operations that we want to avoid executing again?

Comment: @PabloMartínez Yes, use `.combineLatest()` instead of the `.forkJoin`. You really need to specify the requirements properly from the start in the question

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. The needs have not changed! I asked with an example code, and the problem with it is that setting the contact info may happen before the form is completely built with the selects data. I noticed that your suggestions slightly changed the original behavior. In my example all 4 requests happen simultaneously, and `this.countries = countries; ...` is not executed when just the contact info changed. I am saying that if I was doing like `this.veryComplexTask(countries)`, it would not make sense to do that again when I just needed to //Do the rest

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer after all that? This is fantastic and @CozyAzure worked hard for it. Come on Pablo, accept it please.